# how to validate array data in ksh

Tags: shell, scripting, ksh

I have an array and I need to validate that the data in each element is either "LOST" or "FOUND" and all caps. In other words i need to validate the data equals the word lost or the word found and that the word is in uppercase. I need to do this in ksh. Note, I do not need to convert from lower to upper. If the data is in lowercase I will send notification.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For ksh93, something like this would work.

```
 $ array=( LoST FOUND FOUND LOST )
 $ for key in ${!array[@]}; do
     [[ ${array[key]} == +(LOST|FOUND) ]] && continue       
     print -u2 "${array[key]} at key $key"
 done
 LoST at key 0
 $
```

Comment: how do I check for uppercase only...so that regardless of the word it must be in uppercase?

Comment: Try `[[ ${word} == +([A-Z]) ]] && echo ok || echo no`